# Hibernate/JPA auto creates foreign key instead of using exisiting foreign key in many to one association

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I use:

- SpringBoot 1.5.1
- MariaDB/MySQL 10.1.14/15.1
- org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
- Hibernate5 (SpringBoot default)

This is the SQL-Table-Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE salaries (
emp_no      BIGINT          NOT NULL,
salary      BIGINT          NOT NULL,
from_date   DATETIME        NOT NULL,
to_date     DATETIME        NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees (emp_no),
PRIMARY KEY (emp_no, from_date)
)
```

This is the entity on the many-side of the association (using an embedded id):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "salaries")
public class Salary {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmpIdFromDatePK empId;

    @Column(name = "to_date", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date toDate;

    @Column(name = "salary")
    private Long salary;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @MapsId("empId")
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "salaries_ibfk_1"), name = "emp_no", referencedColumnName = "emp_no")})
    private Employee employee;

    public Salary() {
        super();
    }

    //...
}
```

The key class:

```
@Embeddable
public class EmpIdFromDatePK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "emp_no")
    private Long empId;

    @Column(name = "from_date", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fromDate;

    public EmpIdFromDatePK() {
        super();
    }

    //....
}
```

And the entity on the one-side of the association:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "emp_no")
    private Long empId;

    //...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    private List<Salary> salaryList;

    //...
}
```

PROBLEM: When I am using the ManyToOne association (for example in a select where an employee is joined with a salary record) a second foreign key is created in the database:

```
CONSTRAINT `FKjojacp79fphmajxrdll8fvf5o` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_no`) REFERENCES `employees` (`emp_no`),
CONSTRAINT `salaries_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_no`) REFERENCES `employees` (`emp_no`)
```

QUESTION: How can I avoid this behavior?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try with:

```
@JoinColumn(name="emp_no", referencedColumnName="emp_no")
@ForeignKey(name="salaries_ibfk_1")
```

?

Comment: My bad - since it is only a single column foreign key, a plain `@JoinColumn` solves the problem: `@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "salaries_ibfk_1"), name = "emp_no", referencedColumnName = "emp_no")`. Thank you! PS: `@ForeignKey` not nested as you described didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

JPA 2.1 only supports to define foreign keys via [@ForeignKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html) annotation.

so if you are using JPA old version than 2.1, i think you can't do it